# python: create directory structure in Json format from s3 bucket objects

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, python-3.8

Am getting objects in a s3 buckets using following

```
s3 = boto3.resource(
    service_name='s3',
    aws_access_key_id=key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=secret
)
for summary_obj in s3.Bucket(bucket_name).objects.all():
    print(summary_obj.key)
```

Its giving me all object like this

```
'sub1/sub1_1/file1.zip',
'sub1/sub1_2/file2.zip',
'sub2/sub2_1/file3.zip',
'sub3/file4.zip',
'sub4/sub4_1/file5.zip',
'sub5/sub5_1/file6.zip',
'sub5/sub5_2/file7.zip',
'sub5/sub5_3/file8.zip',
'sub6/'
```

But i want to have a list of json of all objects with proper directory structure like this to show in my app

```
[
{'sub1': [
    {
        'sub1_1': ['file1.zip'] // All files in sub1_1 folder
    },
    {
        'sub1_2': ['file2.zip'] // All files in sub1_2 folder
    },

]},
{'sub2': [
    {
        'sub2_1': [
            'file3.zip'
        ]
    }
]},
{'sub3': [
    'file4.zip'
]},
{'sub4': [
    {
        'sub4_1': [
            'file5.zip'
        ]
    }
]},
{'sub5': [
    {
        'sub5_1': [
            'file6.zip'
        ]
    },
    {
        'sub5_2': [
            'file7.zip'
        ]
    },
    {
        'sub5_3': [
            'file8.zip'
        ]
    }
]},
{'sub6': []}
]
```

what is the best way to do this in python3.8?

Answer (score 0):

I give it a try and the closest I could get to your json was through **recursion** which works with any level of sub-folders and folders:

```
from collections import defaultdict  

objects=['sub1/sub1_1/file1.zip',
'sub1/sub1_2/file2.zip',
'sub2/sub2_1/file3.zip',
'sub3/file4.zip',
'sub4/sub4_1/file5.zip',
'sub5/sub5_1/file6.zip',
'sub5/sub5_2/file7.zip',
'sub5/sub5_3/file8.zip',
'sub5/sub5_3/file9.zip',
'sub5/sub5_3/sub5_4/file1.zip',
'sub5/sub5_3/sub5_4/file2.zip',
'sub6/']

#print(objects)

def construct_dict(in_list, accumulator):
  if not in_list:
    return
  else:
    if in_list[0] not in accumulator:
      accumulator[in_list[0]] =  defaultdict(list)  
    return construct_dict(in_list[1::], accumulator[in_list[0]])

accumulator = defaultdict(list)
for obj in objects:
  construct_dict(obj.split('/'), accumulator)

print(json.dumps(accumulator))
```

Which gives (the content is same, but structure a bit different):

```
{
  "sub1": {
    "sub1_1": {
      "file1.zip": {}
    },
    "sub1_2": {
      "file2.zip": {}
    }
  },
  "sub2": {
    "sub2_1": {
      "file3.zip": {}
    }
  },
  "sub3": {
    "file4.zip": {}
  },
  "sub4": {
    "sub4_1": {
      "file5.zip": {}
    }
  },
  "sub5": {
    "sub5_1": {
      "file6.zip": {}
    },
    "sub5_2": {
      "file7.zip": {}
    },
    "sub5_3": {
      "file8.zip": {},
      "file9.zip": {},
      "sub5_4": {
        "file1.zip": {},
        "file2.zip": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "sub6": {
    "": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i need a list that will contain all files in a folder. In your code its giving a dict